# Spring OAuth2 missing converter for DefaultOAuth2Token

Tags: converters, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring OAuth version 2.0.7. From reading the source code I think the endpoint /oauth/token should have the DefaultRequestTokenConverter configured, but I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken
```

It appears there are no producible media types found in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor:

```
if (returnValue != null && producibleMediaTypes.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No converter found for return value of type: " + returnValueClass);
}
```

In any case, I also tried setting a converter explicitly for the endpoints:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints.accessTokenConverter(new DefaultAccessTokenConverter()).tokenStore(tokenStore());
}
```

The exception still occurs.

I also tried setting the message converters in my Spring MVC config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new FormOAuth2AccessTokenMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new FormOAuth2ExceptionHttpMessageConverter());
    }
}
```

But the exception still occurs.

I am confused where to set the message converters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, adding the following in the project's pom.xml resolves this missing converter error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```